# set Model value to CKeditor in MVC Edit View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

i use CKEditor in Create view for save Text to Database Model  using below code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace("Body", { htmlEncodeOutput: true });

            </script>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

i use `CKEDITOR.instances['Body'].setData(@Model.Body);` but it not work
but when i put this code in Edit view CKEditor Dont show returned model text
how can i set model string field to ckeditor?

Comment: can you try using Html.TextAreaFor instead of  @Html.EditorFor?

Comment: @HanyHabib what is different ??

Comment: Check the rendered html output. I think your editor for will give input type text and textarea for will be textarea. If this solved it for you tell me will post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use TextAreaFor instead of EditorFor:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace("Body", { htmlEncodeOutput: true });

        </script>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```